# Dojo making application loading slow

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, dojo, xpages-extlib

The mobile application developed using xpages and mobile extension lib. is loading extremely slow on mobile devices. To study the comparative statistics, another plain web HTML was served from Domino server. We found that the plain web HTML loading was very quick and the reason for slow loading was DOJO. Following is the snap shot of the mobile page which is getting loaded slowly.Any tips on how Dojo loading can be made faster?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" dojoParseOnLoad="true"
dojoTheme="true" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex"
xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom" >
<xp:this.resources>

<xp:dojoModule name="dojox.grid.DataGrid"></xp:dojoModule>
<xp:dojoModule name="dojox.data.JsonRestStore"></xp:dojoModule>
<xp:dojoModule name="dijit.form.Button"></xp:dojoModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

In application properties XPages tab check **[x] Use runtime optimized JavaScript and CSS resources**. It will combine the Domino provided JS and CSS files into one file.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show network tab with number of requests from FF or Chrome?
There are could be much more requests for JS/CSS you simply do not see in HTML, rather they load dynamically.